# move_uploaded_file() can not move uploaded file

Tags: php

In my php code this method move_uploaded_file() always return false and moving uploaded file failed!!! I just check the variables value and they were ok.

- echo $fileName--> /tmp/php7KMo5C.pdf
- echo $dest --> images/pics/s1aerj875k.pdf
- var_dump(move_uploaded_file($source, $target1)) --> bool(false)

This is my code behide.

```
<?php
function uploadMain($name,$size,$arr,$way)
{
          $result = array();
          chmod("images", 0770); 
          $imagename = $_FILES[$name]["name"];
          if(!$imagename == "")
          {
           if ($_FILES[$name]["error"] == 0){ 

               if ($_FILES[$name]["size"] < $size){

                    $filename = basename($imagename);

                     $ext = strtolower(substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1));
                     foreach($arr as $value) {

                      if ($ext == $value)
                     {
                        $string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
                        for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
                            $pos = rand(0,38);
                            $str .= $string{$pos};                             
                    }

                    $str .=".$ext";
                                   $imagename = $str;
                    $fileName = $_FILES[$name]["tmp_name"].".$ext";

                    //$imagetype = $_FILES['picture']['type'];

                    $dest = $way.$imagename;
                   try {
                    echo($FILES[$name]);
                    echo("<br \>"); 
                        echo($fileName);
                    echo("<br \>");
                    echo($dest);
                    var_dump(move_uploaded_file($fileName, $dest));
                    move_uploaded_file($fileName, $dest);

                   } catch (Exception $e) {
                       $result["msg"] = "error on uploading file";
                   }
                   $result[$name] = $dest;
                    }
                    else {$result["msg"] = "file type not allowed";
                    }
                  }

                 }
                else  {$result["msg"] = "file size not allowed";
                }
                } 
                    else  {$result["msg"] = "error on uploading file";
                    }
             } 
     return  $result;
}
?>
```

I also set 777 permissions on the folders

Comment: Turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and tell is the error that happens when you call `move_uploaded_file`.

Comment: Doing `move_uploaded_file` twice is a bad idea

Comment: check for directory also that directory is exist or not using "file_exists()" function.

Comment: @u_mulder  I removed the second one, but no change

Comment: It seems that the $filename (temp file) didnt exists on /tmp anymore.